# Filter elasticsearch results to contain only unique documents based on one field value

Tags: elasticsearch

All my documents have a `uid` field with an ID that links the document to a user. There are multiple documents with the same `uid`.

I want to perform a search over all the documents returning only the highest scoring document per unique `uid`.

The query selecting the relevant documents is a simple `multi_match` query.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need a [`top_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation.

And for your specific case:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      ...
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "top-uids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "uid"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_uids_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "_score": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query above does perform your `multi_match` query and aggregates the results based on `uid`. For each uid bucket it returns only one result, but after all the documents in the bucket were sorted based on `_score` in descendant order.

Comment: It there any good way to paginate through the resulting buckets?

Comment: It seems there's a long discussion about this in [github](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4915). And it's not the only issue where this was discussed.

Answer (score 18):

In [ElasticSearch 5.3](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/search-request-collapse.html) they [added](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/22337) support for field collapsing. You should be able to do something like:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "this is a test", 
      "fields": [ "subject", "message", "uid" ] 
    }
  },
  "collapse" : {
    "field" : "uid" 
  },
  "size": 20,
  "from": 100
}
```

The benefit of using field collapsing instead of a top hits aggregation is that you can use pagination with field collapsing.

Comment: This is nice, but doesn't work on text fields.

Comment: Correct, the query can be, just the field you collapse on can't be. From the docs "The field used for collapsing must be a single valued keyword or numeric field with doc_values activated". So it works for something like a UUID or a URL, etc. If it is applicable to the data you could use a multi-field approach as described in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html to have the field be available as both text and keyword.