# How to sort documents stored in elasticsearch based on combination of fields

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, search

What I want to achieve is if have documents like:

```
{
"name": "xyz",
"price": "100"
},
{
"name": "xyz",
"price": "100"
},
{
"name": "abc",
"price": "100"
}
```

I want result as:

```
{
"name": "xyz",
"price": "100"
},
{
"name": "abc",
"price": "100"
},
{
"name": "xyz",
"price": "100"
}
```

So, it is more like moving duplicates to bottom of results based on the combination of fields stored in elastic. I don't want to do this on the client side because I have to paginate over the result.

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886477/how-to-remove-duplicate-search-result-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: @Eli In my case I don't want to remove duplicates. I just want to append them to the end of the list.