# Filter results to remove documents with the same field value based on another field value (without aggregation)

Tags: elasticsearch

Given the following 4 objects in an elasticsearch index:

```js
"hits": [
  {
    "_id": "0:0",
    "_source": {
      "id": 0,
      "version": 0,
      "published": true
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "0:1",
    "_source": {
      "id": 0,
      "version": 1,
      "published": false,
      "latest": true
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "1:0",
    "_source": {
      "id": 1,
      "version": 0,
      "published": true
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "1:1",
    "_source": {
      "id": 1,
      "version": 1,
      "published": true,
      "latest": true
    }
  }
]
```

I would like to find the documents using these rules:

- with `published:true`
- no duplicate `id`
- for documents with the same `id` the highest `version` should be returned.

So for the above I'd like to get `0:0` and `1:1`:

```js
"hits": [
  {
    "_id": "0:0",
    "_source": {
      "id": 0,
      "version": 0,
      "published": true
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "1:1",
    "_source": {
      "id": 1,
      "version": 1,
      "published": true,
      "latest": true
    }
  }
]
```

I'm aware that I can use [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/top-hits.html), but I'd like to know if this is possible without it, such that the main `hits.hits` array will contain these results.

I'd probably do the collapsing as follows:

```js
{ 
  query  : {...},
  aggs : {
    ids: {
      terms: {
          field: "id"
      },
      aggs:{
          dedup:{
            top_hits:{ size:1, sort: {version : 'desc'} }
          }
        }    
    }
  }
}
```

The reason I'm hoping to avoid using [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/top-hits.html) is that I'll need to update the  result parser in our application. Also the `size` field will not work correctly if I do so.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509045/filter-elasticsearch-results-to-contain-only-unique-documents-based-on-one-field?rq=1), it's not possible without using the `top_hits` aggregation. I think what I was trying to achieve wasn't the best use of aggregation. Instead I'm going to adjust the index model by adding `latestPublished` true to the relevant models, allowing the query to be `{ term: { latestPublished: true}}`.