# Azure Search- order facets by highest scored document in each facet

Tags: faceted-search, azure-cognitive-search

Is there a way the facets in Azure Search can be ordered by the **highest scored document** in each facet. The default approach is ordered by number of documents in each facet which not as useful when match accuracy is critical. I understand the 'sort' is within the facet- not across facets.

I am hoping that this will help solve the following need in an indirect way
[Azure Search- replicating result of nested SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823984/azure-search-replicating-result-of-nested-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Azure Search only supports sorting facets by document count or value, not by document score. Feel free to suggest this as a new feature on [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/filters/top)