# Elasticsearch query + aggs - return only the aggs data

Tags: elasticsearch

I was able to model a way to return a set of documents deduplicated by field from the accepted answer in this post:

[Filter elasticsearch results to contain only unique documents based on one field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509045/filter-elasticsearch-results-to-contain-only-unique-documents-based-on-one-field)

The problem is the response payload includes several of the full documents first, followed by the `aggregations` object, whereas I only want the `aggregations` object returned.  How would I do this?  I tried playing with different variations of `_source` to limit what's returned, but not surprisingly, none of my attempts are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the `size = 0` parameter in your elasticsearch query if you wish to return just aggregations results.

The structure of the query will look like this:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {},
    "aggs": {}
}
```